# Is there any Snowflake SQL function which can I modify the limit type in Between clause?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, between

I'm looking for a function which can modify the limit type in between clause. eg:
`Date Between A and B` includes A and B dates. But If the option I'm looking for is for include A and exclude B or viceversa. There is any function available to use instead of use

```
Date >=A and Date<B
```

?
The problem is to change the > instead of >= (the same for <) with the clause BETWEEN

I tried to look for in the community but I didn't find this specific case. SF doc neither have clearly this question solved

Comment: I don't think there is an OOB function for that, but you can always create a UDF that does this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes this is always an option, but I wanted to explore any other OOB already working. Everything aims that I will do that at the end

Comment: Surely creating a UDF is more effort than just typing out Date >A and Date<B

Comment: Full agreed. Thanks both. I'll probably type as it